# $\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{\int_Rfg \, dx:\int_R|g|\,dx=1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. I know $\|f\|_\infty=\sup\{\int_Rfg \, dx:\int_R|g|\,dx=1\}$, but how to show there exists a $g$, with $\|g\|_1=1$ on which the supremum is attained?

I know $\|f\|_\infty\ge\sup\{\int_Rfg \, dx:\int_R|g|\,dx=1\}$ can be shown by Holder inequality, and $\|f\|_\infty\le\sup\{\int_Rfg \, dx:\int_R|g|\,dx=1\}$ can be done by taking $A:=\{x|f(x)\ge\|f\|_{\infty}-\epsilon\}$ for any $\epsilon$ and $g=\frac{\chi_A}{\mu(A)}$, by which we can get $\int fg\le (\|f\|_{\infty}-\epsilon)\int g=\|f\|_{\infty}-\epsilon$.

But I just can't find a $g$ with $\|g\|_1=1$ to get the supreme, can anybody give a hint?

Comment: What reason do you have to believe the supremum is attained?

Comment: @DavidBowman Because it's a problem from a qualified exam.

Comment: I don't understand why there are 4 "close". Can you give a reason? I am working hard on this problem.